# Deleted x86_64-linux-gnu

Tags: filesystem, delete

I accidentally deleted usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu using `rm -rf`. Do I need to re-install the OS or can I repair it somehow?

Ubuntu 20. something

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details, but I'd not expect any directory named `/x86_64-linux-gnu` in the / directory as you mentioned.  What OS/release are you using?  Did you intend to write `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` as that is different; restore your backups or if it's a desktop system you can re-install without losing data files & having *manually installed* packages auto-reinstalled (if available in Ubuntu repositories)

Comment: In the usr/lib/ dir